# Comparação de Lists de objetos - C#

Tags: c#, lista

Preciso comparar 2 listas de objetos que foram preenchidas via banco de dados, conforme classes abaixo:

```
public class Ausente
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public Int32 RA { get; set; }
}

public class AlunoEstagio
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public Int32 RA { get; set; }
    public String ALUNO { get; set; }
    public Int32 PERIODO { get; set; }
    public String DISCIPLINA { get; set; }
    public char CONCEITO { get; set; }
}
```

A List 1 receberá o objeto Ausente, a list 2 receberá o objeto AlunoEstagio.

Eu gostaria de comparar as 2 listas de forma que quando houver um atributo RA da List 1 presente na List 2, que o objeto correspondente da List 2 seja adicionado em uma terceira lista (List 3).

Não tenho ideia de como realizar essa comparação, poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: O que você já fez? Que problemas encontrou? Mostre algum código, pelo menos tente fazer algo para gente poder ajudar com sua dificuldade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se os 2 tipos fossem iguais, você poderia usar o [Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/vstudio/bb460136), mas como não são, acho que o código abaixo faz o que você precisa:

```
var list3 = from l1 in list1
            join l2 in list2 on l1.RA equals l2.RA
            select new
            {
                l1,
                l2
            };
```

Onde `list1` e `list2` são do tipo `List<Ausente>` e `List<AlunoEstagio>` respectivamente.

Comment: Obrigado Bruno, mas essa variável list3, devo converter para um atributo do tipo List certo? A ideia é exibir o conteúdo em um DataGridView

Comment: É só você mudar o select, selecionando o que você precisa mostrar no grid. Se me disser quais campos precisa, eu altero a resposta pra você.

Comment: E dependendo do controle que for usar, não precisa converter pra list e nem mudar o select, nos campos você pode mudar o bindind pra algo como l1.RA, l2.ALUNO etc...

Comment: Obrigado Bruno, já consegui, só adicionei um .ToList() entre a última chave e o ponto vírgula e funfou ! Me ajudou bastante cara, valeu